# Error creating publication for replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

Using sQL Server Management Studio, I follow the usual steps to create the publication for Replicating for few databases.
For one of them I get the error

> Could not update the metadata for database XXX to indicate that a Change Data Capture job
> has been dropped.
> The failure occurred when executing the command 'msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job'. The error
> returned was 14262: 'The specified @job_id ('') does not exist.'.
> Use the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request.
> Changed database context to 'XXX'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22835)
> For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-
> events/mssqlserver-22835-database-engine-error

I am following this method of configuring things,
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-replication-basic-setup-and-configuration/

and it works for other databases.
What can be the problem ?

The one thing that can say about this database is that it was part of the recent BackUp-Restore and others were not.  And is possible that there was a replication configured for it before.  But, if it is the matter, I don't know what got changed / broken and how to fix it.

There are no jobs on the SQL Server agent that matches
anything about my database (XXX) by name .. so I am confused with the error talking about deleting job.

I Did run the clean up as I knew to do it.  Please, correct me if it is wrong.  Here is what I did for a clean up

```
DECLARE @subscriptionDB AS sysname
SET @subscriptionDB = N'XXX'

-- Remove replication objects from a subscription database.
USE master
EXEC sp_removedbreplication @subscriptionDB
GO 
exec sp_cleanupdbreplication
```

I have also ran these

```
select * from distribution..MSpublisher_databases where 
publisher_db = 'XXX'
select * from distribution..MSpublications where publisher_db = 
  'XXX'
select * from distribution..MSarticles where publisher_db = 
 'XXX'
select * from distribution..MSsubscriptions where publisher_db = 
  'XXX'
```

Comment: I'd follow your instinct of "maybe replication was configured on it before" and call [sp_removedbreplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-removedbreplication-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on it and then try again.

Comment: Thanks.  But, I was doing that and the error still there.  I edited the question with what I ran for clean up

Comment: Given that it's complaining about CDC, did you also try [sp_cdc_disable_db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-disable-db-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: CDC was disabled on the database where i am setting up the replication.  See my answer to my own question, I will provide how solved it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, as suspected, the previously run backUp and restore caused this problem.
The database where I was trying to setup replication from is a DEV server, that was recently restored from Prod.
However, when Backup was done on Prod, it was done with CDC enabled, and the DEV server has no CDC running.
So to resolve the issue, I repeated the BackUp and Restore, but with such sequence:

```
-- ====
-- Disable Database for CDC template
-- ====
USE XXX
GO
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_db
GO
```

**RUN BACKUP OF THE XXX database**

```
-- ====
-- Enable Database for CDC template
-- ====
USE XXX
GO
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db
GO
```

**Restore the XXX Database on the Dev**

Setup the replication on Dev now works for the XXX Database.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you specify `keep_cdc` when doing the restore? Specifically, this being a dev server, you were able to disable CDC on the source database. In a production environment, you won't have that luxury.

Comment: Hmm .. No, I did not.  I am pretty new to this ...  learning as I go

Comment: To be clear, you shouldn't in this situation. I'm wondering out loud though if you restored via the UI provided in SSMS and it provided it for you.

Comment: Yes, via UI.  The only options i selected were to WITH REPLACE

Comment: Got it. It's probably worth setting up the restore operation via the UI and then hitting the "Script..." button that's near the top. That will tell you the T-SQL that _would_ be run if you proceeded with the UI. And, if you're feeling frisky, you use that T-SQL as a basis for future restores (in lieu of the UI).

Comment: This is actually what I am doing .. I am working toward automating Replication.. starting with the UI and moving to scripting